# How to suppress printing variable name while printing its value in sqlplus?

Tags: variables, scripting, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, sqlreportingservice

I am trying to achieve this.

This is my code

```
var cvar varchar2(20) 
exec :cvar := 'variable value'
print cvar
```

This is the current output

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


CVAR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
variable value
```

I want to output only the variable value. Not its name or any other output

```
variable value
```

I tried all these settings. no luck

```
SET DEFINE on
SET HEADING OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET ECHO OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRIMS ON
SET PAGES       1000
SET APPINFO     OFF
SET TIME        OFF
SET TIMING      OFF
SET TERMOUT     ON
SET TRIMS       ON
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `set heading off`:

```
SQL> var cvar varchar2(20)
SQL> exec :cvar := 'variable value'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print cvar

CVAR
--------------------------------
variable value
```

---

```
SQL> set heading off
SQL> print cvar
                                   --> see? No heading here
variable value

SQL>
```

Comment: Not sure, its not working for me. 
I have Version 19.14.0.0.0

Comment: Can you post (by editing the original message you wrote) what you exactly did, just like me? Or attach a screenshot which shows it. Because, it just *works* for me in e.g. Oracle 11gR2 and Oracle 21XE.

Comment: Looks like it works. I was executing the script in SQL developer. It looks like the SQL developer won't honor these settings. It works fine in sqlplus. Thank you!